# Input parametrs as HEX from command line

Tags: c++

I would like to print what the user inserts from the command line as HEX
when i declare my variable as: unsigned char myargv[] = {0x00,0xFF};
it works fine, i get: 11111111
but when i pass my parameters from command line i get different value
Example: myApp.exe FF
i get: 01100010

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void writeToScreen(unsigned char *data);

int main(int argc,unsigned char *argv[]){

    if(argc != 2){
        unsigned char myargv[] = {0x00,0xFF};
        writeToScreen(&myargv[1]);
    }else{
        writeToScreen(argv[1]);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void writeToScreen(unsigned char *data){
    unsigned char dat;
        dat =*(data);
        for (unsigned int i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            if (dat & 1) 
                cout<<"1";
            else
                cout<<"0";
            dat>>=1;
        }
        cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Compare the output if you use `unsigned char myargv[] = {'F', 'F'};`. Do you see a similarity somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You argument is `FF`. `'F'` is 70 in ASCII, and 70 is 0x46 (0100 0110). You have "0110 0010" which is 0x46 written in reverse.

So first, you need to convert the argument (FF) into a number. Because currently, it's only a string. You can use `strtol` or `std::stringstream` (with `std::hex`) for that for instance.

With strtol:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void writeToScreen(char *data);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    writeToScreen(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}

void writeToScreen(char *data){
    unsigned char dat = strtol(data, NULL, 16);
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        if (dat & 1) 
            cout<<"1";
        else
            cout<<"0";
        dat>>=1;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Beware that the byte is still printed from LSB to MSB.

Comment: Maxime thank you for your help, what if the user enters FFAA45?? Is it possible to make the code accepts more than 8bits??

Comment: @user2768374 Yes of course. But then you can't store it into an unsigned char. And you must change your loop to display more bits.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to input hex parameters into a program as a command line parameter is with the help of Perl as below,

```
./main $(perl -e 'print "\xc8\xce"')
```

This in net effect, will send 2 bytes (0xC8 and 0xCE) of data in to the main program.